# Page curl with fragments or activities

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to implement page curl for fragments or activities. i searched lot and found some examples but they all are working with images.

Can anyone please help me in this implementation.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below link its a good example for page curl on activity:-

http://devappandroid.com/android-beginner/page-curlturn-effect-android

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ or link of this video http://www.mediafire.com/download/9x3qm304nv9i805/PageFlipWithLayout.zip